# Travel in Schengen zone with long term Visa expiry this month but residence permit valid till Mar 2016

Tags: visas, schengen, residency, long-stay-visas, transition-of-visa-status

My wife's Danish long term type D visa and work permit is expiring this month end ("valid until 30-09-15")  but her residence permit issued (for job search) is valid till Mar 2016.

We have travel plans to other Schengen countries from Oct 2nd 2015 and come back home to India by Oct 3rd week (I am travelling from India with a Italian Schengen tourist visa and will join her there).

We are aware that the Danish residence permit allows free travel and stay in schengen region as per the Danish government website, but are concerned will it cause a problem when we end our trip and come back home on port of exit (Denmark) as the visa stamp on her passport still says valid until 31 Sep 2015 ?

Will the current residence permit suffice for our purpose or will she need to get an  additional Schengen Visa stamped which will be valid beyond current visa expiry date?

Comment: The permit replaces the visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The residence permit should be perfectly fine. A jobseeker's residence permit is somewhat less usual but third country nationals who reside long-term in the EU typically only get residence permits (to be renewed every 1 to 10 years depending on the country and status) and can travel on that basis alone. They do not get visas anymore.